# Should I contribute to my RRSP or wait?

Tags: canada, income-tax, tax-deduction, contribution, rrsp

I am Canadian and I have a large amount of RRSP contribution room. I do have money to contribute, but I will have no taxable income this year.

Should I make my RRSP contributions now, or save the money and
contribute it next year when I will have taxable income (and be able to
get a break/refund).

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9484/deferring-claim-of-significant-purchase-of-rrsps

Answer (score 2):

You **can** defer RRSP deductions to future years. So, if you purchase $20,000 in RRSPs this year but had no income, you could use this to offset your income next year when you are making, say, $100,000. For more details, see [Deferring claim of significant purchase of RRSPs](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/9484/deferring-claim-of-significant-purchase-of-rrsps)

Note that I strongly advise you ensure you have sufficient emergency funds prior to purchasing RRSPs.